# How to read this NOT operator?

Tags: java, operators

I don't understand what the **bolded part actually represents**. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

30 does NOT equal to 30 is false OR NOT(17 equals to 17 (true) AND 20 is greater then 21(false)) // i don't get this one, do I just flip everything meaning like -1 before() so the statement would be:
`17!=17(false) && 20<21(true).` I'm lost here. Thanks for any advice.

```
boolean m;
m = ((30!=30) || !(17==17 && 20>21))
SOP(m);
```

true || false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` operator works on a single `boolean` type and returns the opposite of it's value.

Let's break this all down:

```
(30!=30 || !(17==17 && 20>21))
(false  || !(true   && false))
(false  || !(      false    ))
(false  || true ))
(      true      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the comparison to the left of the OR... that is 30 != 30. This is false. So

```
m = (false || !(17==17 && 20>21))
```

Next 17 is equal to 17,

```
m = (false || !(true && 20>21))
```

Next 20 is not > then 21, so false....

```
m = (false || !(true && false))
```

Next true and false is false... so

```
m = (false || !(false))
```

And that allows us to reach

```
m = (false || true)
```

So

```
m = true
```

Answer (score 0):

`m` will equal `true` because...

```
30!=30 = false

17==17 = true

20>21 = false
```

so...

```
( false || ! ( true && false ) )
```

so...

```
( false || ! false )
```

so...

```
( false || true )
```

so..

```
true
```

I always find it helps to expand your calculations so to speak.

Comment: Sleepy head... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This condition will be **`true`**

```
boolean m = (A || B)
```

Here A is `(30!=30)`

```
 and B is `!(17==17 && 20>21)`
```

Obviously, A wiil be **false**;

`!(17==17 && 20>21)` equals to `!(true && false)`, equals to `!false`, equals to `true`.

Then m = `(A||B)` equals to `(false || true)` equals to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through this step by step.

Initial problem:

```
m = ((30!=30) || !(17==17 && 20>21))
```

We know 30 equals 30 so the 30 != 30 is false:

```
m = ((false) || !(17==17 && 20>21))
```

Because it is an or statement, we can remove the false part:

```
m = !(17==17 && 20>21)
```

We know 17 is equal to 17 (or the world would be ending) and 20 is less than 21 so:

```
m = !(true and false)
```

True and false evaluates to false so we have:

```
m = !false
```

This makes m become `true`.